# Set front-facing camera in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I would like to have my app open the camera (presently UIImagePickerController ) front-facing if available.  (Iphone SDK).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's right there in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW31):

```
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

Of course, you'll need to check first if the front camera is actually available. It's also only available starting with iOS 4.0.

Comment: It seems when i set XCode SDK to IOS4 it compile, and it doesn't crash on a device without front camera. It seems the executable can also run on a device where IOS < 4, but I haven't tested all combinations.

Comment: I now get:The Info.plist for application at....specifies a minimum OS version of 4.1, which is too high to be installed on .......

Comment: This is when trying to run on a device where (version <4) after I had to upgrade the SDK to 4.1 because my phone with front-camera were 4.1

Comment: Came across many other answers on SO and all of them suggested using `AVFoundation`.

Answer (score 8):

Try this method of UIImagePickerController:

```
 + (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)cameraDevice
```

This is a class method and UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice can take two values:

```
  - UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear
  - UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront
  Example code:

        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ])
        {
        // do something
        }
```